# Angular 2 Country Prefix to all Routes

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services

I want to setup angular 2 routes like this

htp://localhost/us/home
htp://localhost/us/contact
htp://localhost/in/home
htp://localhost/in/contact

Here us & in are country codes.

I setup using following code
export const routes: Routes = [

```
{
    path: ':country',
    children : [
        { path: '', component: HomePage },
        { path: 'home', component: HomePage },
        { path: 'contact', component: ContactPage },
        { path: 'search', component: SearchPage },
        { path: 'login', component: LoginPage },
        { path: 'signup', component: SignUpPage },
        { path: 'profile', component: ProfilePage},
        { path: '404', component: NotFoundPage},
        { path: '**', redirectTo: '404'}
    ] 
    pathMatch: 'prefix',
    useAsDefault:true
},
{ 
    path: '', 
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: 'us/home'
},
{ path: '404', component: NotFoundPage},
{ path: '**', redirectTo: '404'}
```

];

& working successfully.

But issues i s

htp://localhost/anypath

Not goes to 404

htp://localhost/us/anypath
htt://localhost/in/anypath

above is going to 404 and working correclty

Please check it, Is it correct or not?

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to work because when you added the first route `':country'` it is automatically taking and value you enter as a country.

No matter what url you enter they will alway go into that first route.

So `localhost/anypath` is probably taking you to homepage they same way `localhost/us` would.

You would need to reorganize your routes to be some thing like `'home/:country'` etc.